# How to manage resources in a console app that creates main window in main()?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

In my app I have to create the main window (which in turn dynamically creates other controls) in Program.Main().  I'm having problems with accessing resources (e.g. styles) placed in App.xaml.  The VS2010 IDE can find the resources in its designer but when I run the app I get an exception that a given resource is not found.

If I copy the resources to specific xaml files (e.g. user controls, windows, pages, etc.) then the resources are working as expected.  However, I'd like to avoid duplicating a single resource in every xaml file that uses it.

Also, if I create a non-console app (e.g. wpf) then the same resources in App.xaml work fine.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to slugster's posting [Access ResourceDictionary items programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032294/access-resourcedictionary-items-programmatically) I was able to load the resources programmatically in my app's loaded event.
Example:

```
            ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
            dict.Source = new Uri("../Resources/PageDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative); 
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it does what I wanted.